# PInvoke Marshalling return string array C#

Tags: c#, c, string, delegates, pinvoke

I have this problem, i need to use the reverse pinvoke (a delegate called from C code to C# code), but this delegate return an array of string, that I would be read from C code. This is the typdef for function pointer.

```
typedef wchar_t** (__cdecl TestPassingString)();
```

This is the delegate associated

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate string[] TestPassingString();
```

Inside the C code there is a call to this function pointer, for example:

```
wchar_t** array = callbackTestPassingString();
```

But I have an AccessViolationException, How I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to type the return value as `IntPtr` and marshal manually. You'll also need to know how to determine the length of the array, and how to deallocate it. You might want to consider a different design to this interface.

Comment: I'm wrapping a C library not written by me, I can't change the C interface. Another solution for me, is to call the delegate from C code with args a string array, that i can modify from C# and C see the changes. How can i do?

Comment: Well, you can't do that if you can't change the interface. Again, you need to know how to determine the length of the array and how to deallocate it. You'll need to read the documentation.

Comment: The size of array is 5 everytime, If i change the string array into struct of 5 strings, can be work?

Comment: @andreapetreti No. There is no direct support for `return string[]` in .net . You'll have to marshal it manually. Not too much difficult. The other big question is how you'll free this array.

Comment: the problem is where free this array, if is allocated with Marshalling on C# with AllocHGlobal, i can free it on c code?

Comment: Either the interface can be changed, or it can't. If you are debating how it is allocated, it sounds like it perhaps could be changed. But you said it can't. This confusion is no fun for us.

Comment: The example that I have write here, its only and example, I want to wrap a C library that have a function pointer used as callback like that, I can't change the interface, beacouse for change it, I need to modify a big part of C code of library, but i can write a wrap function, and here i can free the memory.

Comment: OK, so you can change the interface. Anyway, I've run out of enthusiasm.

Answer (score 1):

C-side code:

```
typedef wchar_t** (__cdecl *TestPassingString)();

// The variable containing the callback to C#
TestPassingString callbackTestPassingString;

// The allocator that can be used by C#. The C code must
// use the corresponding deallocator (free in this case) to
// free the memory.
__declspec(dllexport) void* Allocate(size_t bytes)
{
    return malloc(bytes);
}

// Method used to set the callback. You can change it however you want
__declspec(dllexport) void SetCallbackTestPassingString(TestPassingString callback)
{
    callbackTestPassingString = callback;
}

// Test method that uses the callback. Note the free-ing!
__declspec(dllexport) void Test()
{
    wchar_t** array = callbackTestPassingString();

    const int arraySize = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    // Here we deallocate the array and its elements
    // Here I'm using free()... But the only important thing
    // is that you use the corresponding free-er of Allocate()
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    free(array);
}
```

C#-side code:

```
[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr Allocate(IntPtr bytes);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate IntPtr TestPassingString();

[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetCallbackTestPassingString(TestPassingString callback);

[DllImport("CPlusPlusSide.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Test();

// Simple method to copy a string to a IntPtr, including the terminating \0
public static void CopyStringUnicodeToPtr(string str, IntPtr ptr)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
    {
        Marshal.WriteInt16(ptr, j * sizeof(char), str[j]);
    }

    // \0 terminator
    Marshal.WriteInt16(ptr, str.Length * sizeof(char), 0);
}

public IntPtr MyTestPassingString()
{
    string[] strings = new[]
    {
        "Foo",
        "Bar",
        "FooBar",
        "Baz",
        "FooBarBaz",
    };

    IntPtr ptr = Allocate((IntPtr)(strings.Length * IntPtr.Size));

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = strings[i];

        // The +1 is for the terminating \0
        IntPtr ptr2 = Allocate((IntPtr)((str.Length + 1) * sizeof(char)));
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, i * IntPtr.Size, ptr2);

        CopyStringUnicodeToPtr(str, ptr2);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

and then C#-side to initialize the delegate:

```
private TestPassingString TestPassingStringDelegate;

public void InitializeDelegate()
{
    TestPassingStringDelegate = MyTestPassingString;
    SetCallbackTestPassingString(TestPassingStringDelegate);
}
```

Some notes:

- C-side I'm exporting the C allocator (the `Allocate` method), so that the C#-side can use it to allocate memory
- C-side I'm exporting a `SetCallbackTestPassingString` method that C# can use to set the C delegate to a C# method.
- C#-side: **very** important: the lifetime of the `TestPassingStringDelegate` field must be `>=` the time the C-side can call the C# delegate. If `TestPassingStringDelegate` is lost (normally because the object containing the `TestPassingStringDelegate` field is garbage collected) then if the C-side calls the delegate you'll get an error. The simplest way to solve it is to make the `TestPassingStringDelegate` a `static` field.